# Actualizar grafica cada cierto tiempo Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy trabajando en python para generar un grafico con matplotlib, pero lo que quiero es que se tome datos de un diccionario y los grafique en la misma figura sin cerrarlo, que limpie lo que tienen hecho y grafique los nuevos datos cada segundo debe sacar 1 graficar datos nuevos

En el código que tengo ya los grafico cada segundo pero se cierra y se abre la ventana de la grafica y lo quiero es evitar eso

```
        for x in range(0,len(self.tabla["Voltaje"])):
            Vp = self.tabla["Voltaje"][x]
            Ip = self.tabla["Corriente"][x]
            Fp = self.tabla["Factor de Potencia"][x]
            Ve = Vp * 0.707
            Vm = Ve * 1.41
            Ie = Ip *0.707
            Im = Ie * 1.41
            F = 60
            To = 1/F
            ang = 0

            Fs = 30 * F
            Ts = 1/Fs
            Nc = 4
            t = np.arange(0,Nc*To,Ts)
            Yv = Vm * np.sin(2*np.pi*F*t+ang)
            Yi = Im * np.sin(2*np.pi*F*t+(np.arccos(Fp)))
            fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
            color = "tab:red"
            ax1.set_xlabel("Tiempo")
            ax1.set_ylabel("Voltaje", color = color)
            ax1.plot(t,Yv,color = color)
            ax1.tick_params(axis = "y", labelcolor =color)

            ax2 = ax1.twinx()
            color = "tab:blue"
            ax2.set_ylabel("Corriente", color = color)
            ax2.set_ylim((-1*(Ip+1)),(Ip+1))
            ax2.plot(t, Yi, color = color)
            ax2.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor = color)
            plt.grid()
            plt.title("Desfase Voltaje y Corriente")
            plt.show()
            plt.pause(1)
            plt.clf()
            plt.cla()
            plt.close()
```

Comment: Deberías usar la clase `animation` de matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera dejo el código por si a alguien le funciona

Me falta aun depurar el código pero de esta manera me funciona, solo tengo el detalle que si cierro la grafica antes de que termine el for se queda esperando a que termine, tengo que ver la manera de resolver esto

```
plt.ion()

        Vp = self.tabla["Voltaje"][0]
        Ip = self.tabla["Corriente"][0]
        Fp = self.tabla["Factor de Potencia"][0]
        Ve = Vp * 0.707
        Vm = Ve * 1.41
        Ie = Ip *0.707
        Im = Ie * 1.41
        F = 60
        To = 1/F
        ang = 0

        Fs = 30 * F
        Ts = 1/Fs
        Nc = 4
        t = np.arange(0,Nc*To,Ts)
        Yv = Vm * np.sin(2*np.pi*F*t+ang)
        Yi = Im * np.sin(2*np.pi*F*t+(np.arccos(Fp)))

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
        color = "tab:red"
        ax1.set_xlabel("Tiempo")
        ax1.set_ylabel("Voltaje", color = color)
        ax1.tick_params(axis = "y", labelcolor =color)
        ax1.set_ylim(-130,130)
        line1, = ax1.plot(t, Yv, "r-")

        ax2 = ax1.twinx()
        color = "tab:blue"
        ax2.set_ylabel("Corriente", color = color)
        ax2.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor = color)
        line2, = ax2.plot(t, Yi, "b-")


        for x in range(0,len(self.tabla["Voltaje"])):

            Vp = self.tabla["Voltaje"][x]
            Ip = self.tabla["Corriente"][x]
            Fp = self.tabla["Factor de Potencia"][x]
            Ve = Vp * 0.707
            Vm = Ve * 1.41
            Ie = Ip *0.707
            Im = Ie * 1.41
            F = 60
            To = 1/F
            ang = 0

            Fs = 30 * F
            Ts = 1/Fs
            Nc = 4
            t = np.arange(0,Nc*To,Ts)
            Yv = Vm * np.sin(2*np.pi*F*t+ang)
            Yi = Im * np.sin(2*np.pi*F*t+(np.arccos(Fp)))

            ax2.set_ylim((-1*(Ip+1)),(Ip+1))
            line1.set_ydata(Yv)
            line2.set_ydata(Yi)
            line1.set_label("Voltaje {}".format(Vp))
            line2.set_label("Corriente {}".format(Ip))
            fig.legend(loc='upper left')
            fig.canvas.draw()
            fig.canvas.flush_events()
            plt.pause(1)
```